# Bounded of $\ell_p$ norm sequence controlling divergent series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let $p>1$ and suppose that $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a real sequence with positive values such that $x_n\to +\infty$. Suppose further that there is a sequence $y\in \ell^p$ such that $\sum_{n\in \mathbb N}x_n\vert y_n\vert^p\leq 1$. It is intuitive to think that $y_n\to 0$ and thus we should be able to find an upper bound for its norm (not depending on $y$), but I cannot seem to find it. Is this even true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to David Ullrich's comment, it is clear that

$$\inf_nx_n\sum_{n}|y_n|^p\leq\sum_{n}x_n|y_n|^p\leq 1$$
hence
$$\|y\|^p\leq \frac{1}{\inf_nx_n}$$